# Accessing a Java generics stored in a Map

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to access a custom Java generic stored in a map as below.
Unfortunately I get a type mis-match error.
Now, I can cast it to the type I want because but this seems messy to me.
Is there a clean way of doing the assignment?
Thanks

```
public interface BusinessObject {
}

public class SalesItemA implements BusinessObject {
}

public interface BusinessRuleSuite<T extends BusinessObject> {
    public void fire(T shell);
}

public abstract class BusinessRuleSuiteCommon<T extends BusinessObject>
    implements BusinessRuleSuite<T> {
        public synchronized void fire(T bo) {
            // do something with bo;
        }
    }


    public class SalesBusinessRuleSuite extends
        BusinessRuleSuiteCommon<SalesItemA> {
    }


    public class SalesProcessor {

        private final Map<Class<? extends BusinessObject>, BusinessRuleSuite<? extends BusinessObject>> businessRules;

        public SalesProcessor(Map<Class<? extends BusinessObject>, BusinessRuleSuite<? extends BusinessObject>> businessRules) {
            this.businessRules = businessRules;
        }


        public void processItem(SalesItemA sia) {
            /// This assignment doesn't work??? Why?
            BusinessRuleSuite<SalesItemA> p = this.businessRules.get(sia.getClass());
            p.fire(sia);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your goal to change the `processItem` method signature to accept any `BusinessObject`, rather than just a `SalesItemA`?

Comment: That's correct, I want the sales processor to do it's magic on any 'BusinessObject'
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the return type of `get()` is a `BusinessRuleSuite<? extends BusinessObject>`.

This means it will accept anything that inherits from `BusinessObject` during `put()`. But when you use it on the right hand side of an assign, Java can't make assumptions. It has to play safe, so the `get()` behaves as if you had used `BusinessRuleSuite<BusinessObject>` (without the `extends`).

There are two ways to achieve what you want:

1. Use `BusinessRuleSuite<SalesItemA>` in the map declaration
2. Use a cast

Answer (score 1):

because businessRules is a

```
private final Map<Class<? extends BusinessObject>, BusinessRuleSuite<? extends BusinessObject>> businessRules
```

so instead of

```
BusinessRuleSuite<SalesItemA> p = this.businessRules.get(sia.getClass());
```

do

```
BusinessRuleSuite<? extends BusinessObject> p = this.businessRules.get(sia.getClass());
```

the `Map` places no garuantees that for each key ( `Class<K>`, `BusinessRuleSuite<V>` ), `K=V`, which i assume is true in your code.

### alternatively:

```
public class RuleProcessor<T extends BusinessObject> {
  private final Map<Class<T>, BusinessRuleSuite<T>> businessRules;
  public SalesProcessor(Map<Class<T>, BusinessRuleSuite<T>> businessRules) {
    this.businessRules = businessRules;
  }
  // - or have a blank constructor, and add them one by one
  public void add(Class<T> c, BusinessRuleSuite<T> rs) {
    businessRules.add(c, rs);
  }
  public void processItem(T sia) {
    BusinessRuleSuite<T> p = this.businessRules.get(sia.getClass());
    p.fire(sia);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to create a single `SalesProcessor` class, and change its `processItem` method to accept any implementation of `BusinessObject`.

Neal Gafter tried to make this work by using a ["super type tokens"](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html) to expand Josh Block's ["typesafe heterogenous container"](http://developers.sun.com/learning/javaoneonline/2006/coreplatform/TS-1512.pdf) pattern, [but it has some flaws](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2007/05/limitation-of-super-type-tokens.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your map does not contain items of type SalesItemA but of type <? extends BusinessObject>

change

```
BusinessRuleSuite<SalesItemA> p = this.businessRules.get(sia.getClass());
```

to

```
BusinessRuleSuite<BusinessRuleSuite<? extends BusinessObject>> p = this.businessRules.get(sia.getClass());
```

... not actually tested, so this might not work at all.

Comment: p.fire(sia);
won't work with this approach because fire is declared as fire(T o)